# Check if column exists before execute select clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I use a `DataTable` in a foreach loop from sql like:

```
 foreach(var i in tasks)
 {
     // query sql
     var timeOfTasks = db.GetTableBySQL($"exec usp_Get_WorkedProyectTime @TaskTypeCategoryId = '{i.TaskTypeCategoryId}', @TaskId= '{i.TaskId}'");

     // read columns (different rows have different columns)
     var progressToBackCheck = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select dr["ProgressToBackCheck"]).FirstOrDefault();
     var backcheckToCorrection = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select dr["BackcheckToCorrection"]).FirstOrDefault();
     var correctionsToCompleted = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select dr["CorrectionsToCompleted"]).FirstOrDefault();
     var progressToCompleted = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select dr["ProgressToCompleted"]).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Not all task results have the same data rows. And each row doesn't contain all fields. Is there a way to check if a column exists in the result, before I use query for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [DataColumnCollection.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) to check the column is exists in the data table.

```
if (timeOfTasks.Columns.Contains("ProgressToBackCheck"))
{

}
```

You can use this linq to get field, add `where` linq

```
where timeOfTasks.Columns.Contains("ProgressToBackCheck")
```

look like this.

```
var progressToBackCheck = (
            from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows
            where timeOfTasks.Columns.Contains("ProgressToBackCheck")
            select dr["ProgressToBackCheck"]
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'm thinking, is it possible to use a `switch-case` in this case?

Comment: In your case I would use `If` instead of `switch-case`, because every column check should be independent.

Comment: I have a problem using `Contains`, it asking me for Primary key, so I do this:   `timeOfTasks.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { timeOfTasks.Columns["ProgressToBackCheck"] };` but is the same problem with other columns because I can't set primary if one column doesn't exist